# Find last used row and column of excel in c#

Tags: c#

I have used the following code to import excel file into my data table in c#

```
OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(strcon);
Con.open ();
OledbCommand oledbcommand=new oleDbCmmand("select * from [sheat1$",con);
OleDbDataReader dr= oledbCommand. ExecuteReader();
//loading in datatable
Dt.load (dr);
```

Please help me in telling how can I find the last used row and last column in my excel or datatable in c# .

Please help!!!!

Comment: do you cant get last record in excel file ? and last column in last record?

Comment: No. I want the last used row and column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276745/find-the-last-used-row-in-excel-with-c-sharp

Comment: Is there no other way to do like in continuation with what I tried to do...