# Check if Excel Range contains an empty cell

Tags: c#, excel

I have seen a bunch of solutions, but all include either checking the whole range or checking a specific cell in a range.

Is there a way to check if there are ***any*** empty cells in a specific range?

This is what I am currently using, but `thisCount` is always 0, even though I know it should be 27 (27 being the number of occupied cells). I have opened debugging mode to, and I see that the range is in fact the one that I want.

```
range = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[rows][1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[rows][columns]];
double thisCount = this.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(range);
```

Comment: Any insight here in [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14508655/4727183)

Comment: @bjbk at first I didn't think so, but I may actually be able to make it work, if I check that range for used cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a nice rectangular block like **A1:D7** then:

```
=IF(ROWS(A1:D7)*COLUMNS(A1:D7)=COUNTA(A1:D7),"no empties","at least one empty")
```

In *VBA* you would check `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Comment: So it is technically a rectangular block, but it's only one row. Does that change anything? Basically, I am trying to check to see if the last row of the spreadsheet is a row of data or a totals row, which would only have 2 cells filled.