# Filter out (blank) row in pivot table with Excel Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

I have an excel with three worksheets, raw data, pivot table and pivot chart.
Since the raw data will be updated by code with unknown number of rows, I selected the whole column to be the data source. When the pivot table is refreshed, it always get some empty rows in the raw data thus there will be a (blank) row in the pivot table.

I want to filter out the (blank) row in the same program. So far I have read the excel file, but I have no idea on how to filter just the (blank) row, thanks.

```
        Application exApp = new Application();
        Workbook exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(targetPath);
        PivotTable pivotTb = exWbk.Sheets[1].pivotWorkSheet.PivotTables("Report");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make the raw data a Table instead of a standard range.  Click anywhere inside the data, and from the "Insert" tab in the ribbon, select "Table," and Excel will automatically turn your range into a table.

A Table has many advantages over a range, not the least of which is it automatically sizes when rows are added or deleted.  If your automatic refresh is somehow **not** deleting the rows (just the content), that's resolved by something like this (assume "Table1" is the name of your Table):

```
Excel.ListObject lo = exWbk.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["Table1"];
foreach (Excel.ListRow rw in lo.ListRows)
{
    if (exApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rw.Range) == 0)
        rw.Delete();
}
```

2. Change the data source for your pivot table to be the Table (within Excel -- permanently).  This should omit any blank rows.
3. Refresh your pivot table:

   `pivotTb.RefreshTable();`

If you REALLY don't want to convert your range to a table, then I suggest you dynamically modify the source data for your pivot table.

Here's an example of how you could dynamically change the range of your pivot table, using A1:C8 as an example range:

```
Excel.Range r = exWbk.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Range["A1:C8"];
Excel.PivotCache pc = exWbk.PivotCaches().Create(
    Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, r);
pivotTb.ChangePivotCache(pc);
pivotTb.RefreshTable();
```

There are no shortage of suggestions on how to define the used range, but just in case you don't have a way:

[How to get the range of occupied cells in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284388/how-to-get-the-range-of-occupied-cells-in-excel-sheet)