# Is it possible to select all cells where a conditional format is true?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to check an excel worksheet if any of the cells have a conditional format that true.  I have multiple formats that format cells different colors, but I just want to be able to see if any of the conditions are true (don't care which condition).  This example isn't working, but I want to know if I'm on the right track or even possible to do what I'm asking.

```
var lastCell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
var firstCell = ((Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet).Cells[2,1];
var range = ((Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet).Range[firstCell, lastCell]
var r = range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions, true);
```

Comment: Loop through the cells and add them to a list if they match condition? Or use linq if possible

Answer (score 0):

As the `FormatConditions` collection of a range applies to an entire range, I don't believe there's a mechanism to determine the value for each cell in the range.  I think your best bet would be to test the `Formula` in the cell of interest.  *I'm sure this is not what you wanted to hear*.

Get the **used range** with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284388/how-to-get-the-range-of-occupied-cells-in-excel-sheet).  Of course, replacing `xlWorkSheet` with `((Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet)`.

Then, assuming you set it to `range`, loop through the range...

```
for (int r = 1; r <= range.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= range.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
```

...replace the formula/value temporarily with something like (*preface: I almost guarantee this code will not work*)...

```
        string formula = range[r, c].Formula; //or Value, check HasFormula
        for (int i = 1; i <= range.FormatConditions.Count; i++)
        {
            range[r, c].Formula = range.FormatConditions[i].Formula1; // or Formula2 (?)
        }
        bool condition = range[r, c].Value;
        // do work based on the condition

        range[r, c].Formula = formula;
```

... and close the loops.

```
    }
}
```